# Determine the sign of the permutation $f \circ g \circ f \circ g \circ f \circ g \circ f$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f,g \in S_{E}$ such that the sign of $f \circ g \circ f^{-1}$ is $-1$. Determine the sign of the permutation $f \circ g \circ f \circ g \circ f \circ g \circ f$.

Here $S_{E}$ is the permutation group.

I know that I have to insert $f \circ f^{-1}$ or\and $g \circ g^{-1}$ in the statement. Is there anyone is able to help me in this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is well known that for any permutations $\sigma,\tau$, we have 
$$Sign(\sigma\tau)=Sign(\sigma)Sign(\tau) \mbox{ and } Sign(\sigma^{-1})=Sign(\sigma).$$
Hypothesis gives $Sign(fgf^{-1})=Sign(f)^2.Sign(g)=(\pm 1)^2Sign(g)=Sign(g).$

Therefore, $Sign(fgfgfgf)=Sign(f)^4.Sign(g)^3=(\pm 1)^4.(-1)^3=-1$.

Comment: Why $g$ must be $-1$

Comment: for any permutations $\sigma, \tau$ the well known theorem is $sign(\sigma\tau)=sign(\sigma).sign(\tau)$, and also that $sign(\sigma^{-1})=sign(\sigma)$.

Comment: extremely sorry.  misunderstanding your compositon. Repaired answer.